# Display flickering in pygame (how to make my code more efficient)

Tags: python, pygame

Although Python is really slow I want to try to make a 3D game engine in pygame. And I already have a problem: display flickers when I add more than just one object. You can view my code [here](https://github.com/BekhruzSNiyazov/tdge/tree/master/src) (*to view the result you need to run the test.py file, tdge.py functions as a library*). How can I make it more efficient?
Here is the main part of this code:

```
# this function handles the drawing objects on the display
def draw(game, object):

    # updating the background if game.update is True
    if game.update:
        if game.image_path: game.win.blit(game.image, (0, 0))
        else: game.win.fill(game.color)

    # checking the type of the given object
    if type(object) == Cube:

        # getting the height of the game window
        height = game.win.get_height()
        # getting the width of the game window
        width = game.win.get_width()
        # getting the X distance between the object and the user
        distanceX = game.position[0] - object.position[0]
        # getting the Z distance between the object and the user
        distanceZ = game.position[2] - object.position[2]
        # setting the size of the object that user will actually see
        display_size = []
        for size in object.size:
            if game.position[2] < object.position[2]:
                display_size.append(size / distanceZ * 1000)
            else: display_size.append(0)
        # creating a position list, storing the position of an object on a 3D coordinate plane
        position = [width / 2 - distanceX - display_size[0] / 2, height / 2 - object.position[1] - display_size[1] / 2, object.position[2]]

        # if player is not "inside" of the object
        if game.position[0] > position[0] + object.size[0] / 2 or \
            game.position[0] < position[0] - object.size[0] / 2 and \
                game.position[1] > position[1] + object.size[1] / 2 or \
                    game.position[1] < position[1] - object.size[1] / 2 and \
                        game.position[2] > position[2] + object.size[2] / 2 or \
                            game.position[2] < position[2] - object.size[2] / 2:

            # if the rotation of the player is [0, 0, 0]
            if game.rotation == [0, 0, 0]:
                # if the rotation of the object is [0, 0, 0]
                if object.rotation == [0, 0, 0]:
                    # drawing a 2D rectangle
                    pygame.draw.rect(game.win, object.color, ((position[0], position[1]), (display_size[0], display_size[1])))
                # if rotation of the object is not [0, 0, 0]
                else:
                    # if the object is rotated on Y axis
                    if object.rotation[1] != 0:
                        # getting the sizes on X axis
                        y_rotation = object.rotation[1]
                        percent = 100 / (90 / y_rotation)
                        x_size = display_size[0]
                        x0 = x_size / 100 * percent
                        x1 = x_size - x0
                        number = 255 - (255 / 100 * percent)

                        # setting the RGB values
                        color0 = object.color[0] - number if object.color[0] >= number else 0
                        color1 = object.color[1] - number if object.color[1] >= number else 0
                        color2 = object.color[2] - number if object.color[2] >= number else 0

                        # drawing two 2D rectangles based on the data above
                        pygame.draw.rect(game.win, (color0, color1, color2), ((position[0], position[1]), (x0, display_size[1])))
                        pygame.draw.rect(game.win, object.color, ((position[0]+x0, position[1]), (x1, display_size[1])))
                # else:
                    # TODO
                    # write code for displaying object when it is to the right or to the left of the player
                    # pass

        # adding the object if it is not in game.objects
        if object not in game.objects:
            game.objects.append(object)
    else:
        error = "You should provide the object of supported type by this library."
        raise TypeError(error)

    # update the screen so that user will see the difference
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by multiple calls to [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update). An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove all calls to `pygame.display.update()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop:

```py
def start_game(game, code=None):
    # [...]

    while running:
        # [...]

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)
```